# Date format day/month php

Tags: php, date, format

I'm trying to format my date so it shows as (e.g. 7th Nov 2014) or just (e.g. 7th Nov) if possible. Any help would bet great. I know I can do a trim and conditional statement or case statement but wanted to know if there was a php format for this type of date.

Ended up using:

PHP:

$date = date("jS M", strToDate($start_date));

Comment: `$today = date('d-m');` - `$date = date_create()->format('d m Y');`

Comment: You should consider first googling your problem or searching on here.  Show your research, it won't hurt you.

Comment: I did and only found options that would going to help.

Comment: You should at least, paste some of your code that you've tried to output the date. Show your research and workings, and what you have tried.

Comment: You can find exactly what you're asking extremely easily by Googling 'php date format'. In fact, it's the very first result on Google.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can review the [date formats in the PHP manual](https://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

```
$date = new DateTime();
echo $date->format('jS M'); // 20th Aug
echo $date->format('jS M Y'); // 20th Aug 2014
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your input, you can use the SPL [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function:

```
$formatted = date('jS M Y'); // long version: 7th Nov 2014
$formatted = date('jS M'); // short version: 7th Nov
```

Note: SPL = Standard PHP Library

Without a second argument, `date` will take the current timestamp. If you do have an UNIX timestamp as input, your line of code would read:

```
$formatted = date('jS M', $timestamp);
```

If you are given a string as a date - e.g. "2014-11-07", "7 November 2014" or even "+1 week" for relative dates - you need to first convert it to a timestamp, e.g.

```
$formatted = date('jS M', strtotime($timestring));
```

Comment: You beat me to it 65 seconds :D

Comment: But you are using the Date object approach, so it's added value. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHPs date function

```
<?php echo date("d M Y"); ?>
```

output: 7 Nov 2014

or...

```
<?php echo date("d M"); ?>
```

output 7 Nov

(Also, for the th,rd, etc like 7th or 3rd use S)
so: `<?php echo date("dS M Y"); ?>` eg: 7th Nov 2014

You can read full documentation on using Dates in php here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: For the day you should use "j" (without leading zeros) instead of "d". At least, I assume the OP wants it that way.

Comment: You are right Paul, I stand corrected.